# Unable to detect a click on IconButton in a stack in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am using the following code in which I am unable to detect button click on subButtons. The click on main button works just fine as it displays and hides and subButtons. There are three sub-buttons behind the main button and they come out when main button is pressed. I got this code from : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S7KG4prI7A4
I never really understood animations in flutter but this was a good starting point. My knowledge in animation is limited to the to something basic such as Hero Widget.

```
    Expanded(
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ListView.builder ... // Listfview here
                    Positioned(
                        right: 23,
                        bottom: 23,
                        child: Stack(
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Transform.translate(
                              offset: Offset.fromDirection(getRadiansFromDegree(270),degOneTranslationAnimation.value * 100),
                              child: Transform(
                                transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value))..scale(degOneTranslationAnimation.value),
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                child: CircularButton(
                                  color: Provider.of<UserData>(context,listen: false).getPrimaryColor(),
                                  width: 50,
                                  height: 50,
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.note,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                  onClick: (){
                                    print('Noted clicked'); // *Can't Detect*
                                   
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Transform.translate(
                              offset: Offset.fromDirection(getRadiansFromDegree(225),degTwoTranslationAnimation.value * 100),
                              child: Transform(
                                transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value))..scale(degTwoTranslationAnimation.value),
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                child: CircularButton(
                                  color: Provider.of<UserData>(context,listen: false).getPrimaryColor(),
                                  width: 50,
                                  height: 50,
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.camera_alt,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                  onClick: (){
                                    print('Second button');  // *Can't Detect*
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Transform.translate(
                              offset: Offset.fromDirection(getRadiansFromDegree(180),degThreeTranslationAnimation.value * 100),
                              child: Transform(
                                transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value))..scale(degThreeTranslationAnimation.value),
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                child: CircularButton(
                                  color: Provider.of<UserData>(context,listen: false).getPrimaryColor(),
                                  width: 50,
                                  height: 50,
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.report_problem,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                  onClick: (){
                                    //TODO
                                    print ('Three clicked');  // *Can't Detect*
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Transform(
                              transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value)),
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: CircularButton(
                                color: Provider.of<UserData>(context,listen: false).getSecondryColor(),
                                width: 60,
                                height: 60,
                                icon: Icon(
                                  Icons.menu,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                                onClick: (){
                                  print ('clicked'); // WORKS FINE
                                  if (animationController.isCompleted) {
                                    animationController.reverse();
                                  } else {
                                    animationController.forward();
                                  }
                                },
                              ),
                            )
    
                          ],
                        )),
                  ],
                ),
              ),



class CircularButton extends StatelessWidget {

  final double width;
  final double height;
  final Color color;
  final Icon icon;
  final Function onClick;

  CircularButton({this.color, this.width, this.height, this.icon, this.onClick});


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: color,shape: BoxShape.circle),
      width: width,
      height: height,
      child: IconButton(icon: icon,enableFeedback: true, onPressed: onClick),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: A stack is just that, a stack of widgets one on top of the other. The last one in the list is at the top of the stack and is therefore accessible. If it is the same size as all the other items in the stack and in the same position on the screen, then it covers them and they are not accessible. You need to work with sizes and positions to make them all accessible.

Comment: I don't think I would use Stack for multiple buttons. I would go with using columns and rows. Not sure what visual effects you are looking for though and answering on my phone so can't test your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source: https://github.com/letsdoit07/flutter_animated_fab_menu

You have to define the animationController first and the reason why are the buttons not working is you didn't add an IngnorePointer.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Edit As If You want',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController animationController;
  Animation degOneTranslationAnimation,
      degTwoTranslationAnimation,
      degThreeTranslationAnimation;
  Animation rotationAnimation;

  double getRadiansFromDegree(double degree) {
    double unitRadian = 57.295779513;
    return degree / unitRadian;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250));
    degOneTranslationAnimation = TweenSequence([
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(
          tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.2), weight: 75.0),
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(
          tween: Tween<double>(begin: 1.2, end: 1.0), weight: 25.0),
    ]).animate(animationController);
    degTwoTranslationAnimation = TweenSequence([
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(
          tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.4), weight: 55.0),
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(
          tween: Tween<double>(begin: 1.4, end: 1.0), weight: 45.0),
    ]).animate(animationController);
    degThreeTranslationAnimation = TweenSequence([
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(
          tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.75), weight: 35.0),
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(
          tween: Tween<double>(begin: 1.75, end: 1.0), weight: 65.0),
    ]).animate(animationController);
    rotationAnimation = Tween<double>(begin: 180.0, end: 0.0).animate(
        CurvedAnimation(parent: animationController, curve: Curves.easeOut));
    super.initState();
    animationController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      width: size.width,
      height: size.height,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
              right: 23,
              bottom: 23,
              child: Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                children: <Widget>[
                  IgnorePointer(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(
                          0.0), // comment or change to transparent color
                      height: 150.0,
                      width: 150.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Transform.translate(
                    offset: Offset.fromDirection(getRadiansFromDegree(270),
                        degOneTranslationAnimation.value * 100),
                    child: Transform(
                      transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(
                          getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value))
                        ..scale(degOneTranslationAnimation.value),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: CircularButton(
                        color: Colors
                            .yellow, //Provider.of<UserData>(context,listen: false).getPrimaryColor(),
                        width: 50,
                        height: 50,
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.note,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        onClick: () {
                          print('Noted clicked'); // *Can't Detect*
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Transform.translate(
                    offset: Offset.fromDirection(getRadiansFromDegree(225),
                        degTwoTranslationAnimation.value * 100),
                    child: Transform(
                      transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(
                          getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value))
                        ..scale(degTwoTranslationAnimation.value),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: CircularButton(
                        color: Colors
                            .purple, //Provider.of<UserData>(context,listen: false).getPrimaryColor(),
                        width: 50,
                        height: 50,
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.camera_alt,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        onClick: () {
                          print('Second button'); // *Can't Detect*
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Transform.translate(
                    offset: Offset.fromDirection(getRadiansFromDegree(180),
                        degThreeTranslationAnimation.value * 100),
                    child: Transform(
                      transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(
                          getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value))
                        ..scale(degThreeTranslationAnimation.value),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: CircularButton(
                        color: Colors
                            .blue, //Provider.of<UserData>(context,listen: false).getPrimaryColor(),
                        width: 50,
                        height: 50,
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.report_problem,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        onClick: () {
                          //TODO
                          print('Three clicked'); // *Can't Detect*
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Transform(
                    transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(
                        getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value)),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: CircularButton(
                      color: Colors
                          .red, //Provider.of<UserData>(context,listen: false).getSecondryColor(),
                      width: 60,
                      height: 60,
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.menu,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      onClick: () {
                        print('clicked'); // WORKS FINE
                        if (animationController.isCompleted) {
                          animationController.reverse();
                        } else {
                          animationController.forward();
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ))
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}

class CircularButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final double width;
  final double height;
  final Color color;
  final Icon icon;
  final Function onClick;

  CircularButton(
      {this.color, this.width, this.height, this.icon, this.onClick});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: color, shape: BoxShape.circle),
      width: width,
      height: height,
      child: IconButton(icon: icon, enableFeedback: true, onPressed: onClick),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I found IgnorePointer so counterintutive otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Additional info: I had a similar situation and in my case switching the Stack for a Column ( with all due differences ) solved the problem.